# How to change the backgound color and deactivate the inactive botton

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have 2 buttons, button1 is called `(green)` and button2 is called `(blue)`.

Clicking on the button `(Green)` changes the backcolor to green and deactivates the `(Blue)` button, while clicking on the button `(blue)` changes the backcolor to blue and deactivates the `(greenn)` button.

At the start of the application, the button `(Blue)` should be deactivated :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        BackColor = Color.Green; 
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried doing so far

Comment: Downvotes is the only thing what appears *asap* ;)

Comment: who cares about downvotes :) we'e here to learn, and I'm trying to know how to show that, I'm new here

Answer (score -1):

Excellent! We can work with your code now :)

As for changing the button backcolors and enabled states, your existing code should look like below. You must define the object that you are trying to manipulate, even when you are in a method fired by that object. Also, I added the option of turning the opposite button white so that when it is clicked again in the future it can change to the desired color again.

Since each button sets its opposite as not enabled and white, you will get the effect that only one button (the one you clicked last) can be active at a time.

Let me know if this has helped!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{ button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
  button1.Enabled = true;
  button2.BackColor = Color.White;
  button2.Enabled = false;} 
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
  { button2.BackColor = Color.Blue;
     button2.Enabled = true;
     button1.BackColor = Color.White;
     button1.Enabled = false; }
```

As for your blue button being disabled when form is activated, you should find this event in your code (I have Form1 as your form name, change it if you have named your form something else). Just set the button as disabled at this point, or you can have it set as enabled = false as the default in the properties tab.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{button2.Enabled = false;}
```

Comment: the only think I can do is changing my backcolor by this code :
 BackColor = Color.Green; for example ,  and also desactivating the button by going to propeties (enabled), but still I don't kno whow to do something exactly like I explained above in the execice

Comment: @MattCash This is not an answer

Comment: First time using app, I was trying to comment instead. I cannot figure out how to remove the answer either...

Comment: @character b. You should copy and paste your existing code in your original question to show us what you have so far. To programmatically enable / disable a control like you would in properties, you would simply write

Comment: (name of button).enabled = true (or false).                                                       My apologies for me messing up all of my posts, the mobile app is not forgiving of mistakes.

Comment: hmm I just joined this site 10 minutes ago,so I still don't know how it works